# How to attach particles to moving object

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I've created an PowerUpTrail.sks (particle thingy)
And I'm trying to attach it to a moving object

```
func SpawnPowerUp(){

    let PowerUp = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PowerUp.png")
    let MinValue = self.size.width / 8
    let MaxValue = self.size.width - 20
    let SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    PowerUp.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height - 100)

    //Physics
    PowerUp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: PowerUp.size)
    PowerUp.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PowerUp //Sätter unikt ID för Enemy, hämtat från PhysicsCategory som vi gjorde där uppe
    PowerUp.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PowerUp //Kolla om Enemy nuddar Bullet
    PowerUp.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    PowerUp.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-128, duration: 5)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    PowerUp.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))
    PowerUp.runAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(5, duration: 5))


    /* this does not work!
    let PowerUpTrail = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "PowerUpTrail.sks")
    PowerUpTrail!.targetNode = self
    PowerUpTrail!.position = PowerUp.position
    self.addChild(PowerUpTrail!)
    */

    self.addChild(PowerUp)

}
```

The particlethingy spawns but it doesnt follow the object. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to make one node's position track another is to use the node hierarchy: make the particle emitter a child node of the powerup sprite.

```
let powerUp = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PowerUp.png")
// ...
let powerUpTrail = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "PowerUpTrail.sks")!
powerUpTrail.targetNode = self
powerUp.addChild(powerUpTrail)
```

(Also note some Swift style tips: initial-cap is conventionally for type names only; use initial-lowercase for variable names. And unwrap your optional from `SKEmitterNode(fileNamed:)` once when you create it instead of every time you use it thereafter.)

Comment: That was awesome and super simple. Thanks a ton Rickster!

I'm very new to Swift, thank you for guiding me. How do i "unwrap"? Can you give an example of a "wrapped" versus an "unwrapped" one? I have no clue. Super thanks once again.

Comment: `SKEmitterNode(fileNamed:)` returns an *Optional* — something that reflects the possibility of there being a value (the emitter node you want to load) or no value (because, say, the filename is wrong). To get at the actual value, you have to "unwrap" it using the `!` operator. It's better to do that once, right when you load `powerUpTrail`, than to do it many times thereafter. Optionals are one of the big important topics in Swift, so I'd highly recommend reading up on them in [the book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/)